# Cannot install demo site happylager

Tags: installation

I have trouble installing the demo site 'happylager'.

Windows 8.1 
WAMP 3.0.4 - MySQL 5.7.11 - PHP 5.6.19 - Apache 2.4.18

I follow the instructions from https://github.com/pixelandtonic/HappyLager and when I import the .sql file I get this error message.

[image: error message after .sql import]

When I head back to happylager.dev/admin I get the installation screen, not the login screen as it is described in the repo. What do you think is the problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Related? https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/18919/db-back-up-gives-syntax-errors-on-import-in-new-db#comment25689_18919

Comment: It was associated with my phpMyAdmin version (4.5.5.1). I upgraded to the last version and it worked fine. Thank you for pointing to the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated phpMyAdmin to the latest stable version and it worked!